# RequestScope() and Kernel.Get<> in Ninject

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, webrequest

If I define a binding in ninject with `ReqeustScope()`, and then call `Kernel.Get<T>` on that type outside of a request what will the scope of the resolved object be?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do a similar thing. I have resolutions that are made during the request and some factories persist after the request. Using NamedScope and ContextPreservation didn't help me in resolving things in the context of one logical request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we study the [StandardScopeCallbacks](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Infrastructure/StandardScopeCallbacks.cs) we can see that the callback for the request scope is the current HTTP context. The callback for a transient object is null. If you resolve a service outside of a request the current HTTP context is null. Thus, the scope is implicit transient as apparent of the following test.

```
[Test]
public void ServiceInRequestScopeIsImplicitTransientWhenHttpContextIsNull()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<ServiceInRequestScope>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    Assert.That(HttpContext.Current, Is.Null);

    var service0 = kernel.Get<ServiceInRequestScope>();
    var service1 = kernel.Get<ServiceInRequestScope>();

    Assert.That(service0, Is.Not.SameAs(service1));
}
```